# load ckeditor with jquery once loaded if try to use toolbar it reloads the editor and does not change text

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I load the chek editor in a .php external file with jquery

```
    <script src='../js/jquery-2.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <div id='cippa'>
        <script>

    $('#cippa').click(function(){
// load page on click
    $('#cippa').load('edit_news_inc.php?id_user=".$id_user."&id=".$news[$n]['id']."&file_id=N&type=body_it&save=0&field=body_it');
});
    </script>
    <a href='javascript:void()' id='cippa'>
```

in the .php file I call:

```
    <script src='../ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script>

        <form name=".$type." method=post action='add_news.php?id_user=".$id_user."&id=".$id."&file_id=N&type=".$type."&save=1&field=".$type."'>
        <textarea id='pippo' name=\"body_it\" cols=50 rows=4>".utf8_encode($news[$n]['body_it'])."</textarea>

        <script>

        CKEDITOR.replace( 'pippo', {
language: 'it',
//  uiColor: '#14B8C4',
enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
    } );

    </script>

        <input type='submit' class='inputButtonAdmin' value='Save body IT'> 
        </form>
```

All works well if I edit the text but if I try to use the toolbar (ie. B or Italics) it reloads the Editor and loses changes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, if it can help someone

```
    <script src='/js/jquery-2.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <div id='body_it'>
    <span class='orange'>Corpo Italiano:<a href='#' id='reg_link'>OKOKOKOKOK</a>
    <img src='/images/edit.png' height=18 width=18 alt='edit'><span class='black'>(".$lang['edit'].")</span></a></span>
    <br>".utf8_encode($news[$n]['body_it'])."

    </div>
    <script>
     $('#reg_link').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#body_it').load('edit_news_inc.php?id_user=".$id_user."&id=".$news[$n]['id']."&file_id=N&type=body_it&save=0&field=body_it');
    });
    </script>
```

and the external .php file

```
       <script src='../ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script>

        <form name=".$type." method=post action='add_news.php?id_user=".$id_user."&id=".$id."&file_id=N&type=".$type."&save=1&field=".$type."'>
        <p>
        <textarea name='body_it' class='ckeditor'>".utf8_encode($news[$n]['body_it'])."</textarea>

        <script>

        CKEDITOR.instance( 'body_it', {
language: 'it',
//  uiColor: '#14B8C4',
enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
    } );

    </script>
     </p>
    <p>
        <input type='submit' class='inputButtonAdmin' value='Save body IT'> 
        </form>
        </p>
```